# Simple return index in Pandas with .shift

Tags: pandas, indexing, time-series

I would like to calculate a simple index series, but somehow it does not work. The dataframe has two columns: a index column and the percentage change to add:

```
      Indice  PerChange
1        1   0.024412
2        1   0.036074
3        1   0.027329
4        1   0.027981
```

This is my code:

```
df3["Indice"] = df3["Indice"] * (df3["PerChange"] + df3["Indice"].shift(1))
df3.at[1, 'Indice'] = 1
```

For which I get the following output:

```
 Indice  PerChange
1   1.000000   0.024412
2   1.036074   0.036074
3   1.027329   0.027329
4   1.027981   0.027981
```

However, what I would like to see is:

```
 Indice  PerChange
1   1.000000   0.024412
2   1.036074   0.036074
3   1.064388   0.027329
4   1.094171   0.027981
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are basically looking for the cumulative product:

```
s = df['PerChange'] + 1
s.at[1] = 1

df['Indice'] = s.cumprod()
```

Comment: This was the missing function I looked for! Thx